# не компилируется проект в idea ошибка error cannot create empty file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите решить проблему,перестали компилироваться проекты, произошло после того как нажал на апдейт ,после этого снес старую версию поставил новую и все равно проблема та же , ...еще у до этого у меня были проблемы с кодировкой.

Comment: и еще...у меня на компе перестали запускаться ранее созданные JAR ники

Comment: и Еклипс перестал запускаться...java на месте вроде...попробую переставить.

Comment: У вас там путь какой-то непонятный, возможно косяк из-за кирилицы в пути

Comment: спасибо за ответ, тоже про это подумал, может быть что это из-за того что Windows10 не все символы корректно отображает?

Comment: Нет, это приколы новых сред от jetbrains, просто нужно смириться и убрать кирилличнскте символы

Comment: понятно...у меня проблема решилась, внизу написал как...как не крути иногда кирилические символы нужны...у меня до этого было, что в idea выдавало ошибку даже на комментарии кирилическими символами...

Answer (score 0):

все начало работать после того как в настройках убрал галочку "Использовать Юникод"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]