# Не могу ничего запустить в intellij idea

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не помогает переустановка intellij idea

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860239/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B2-idea-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-error-cannot-create-empty-file

Answer (score 0):

У тебя пользователь на русском языке  - возможно в этом причина.

Создай нового и проверь.